# Too many redirects while serving php app with nginx

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose

Hi I am trying to dockerize a php application and serve it using nginx. It was previously working fine but not it is giving me this error `localhost redirected you too many times.` and the docker container is showing this logs `php-fpm      | 172.21.1.2 -  26/Sep/2022:05:48:53 +0000 "GET /index.php" 303`. I am trying to expose the nginx container on port 80. Php and nginx container shares the same directory in which the code exists. Any help would be appreciated.

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    client_max_body_size 308M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;
    

    root /application/tcf;
    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
}
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --user=root
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "database"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "mysql"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    # build: ./nginx
    container_name: webserver
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  php-fpm:
    build: ./
    container_name: php-fpm
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}
```

checks if the requested path exists in the Nginx container. You start out by calling it with /index.php. index.php doesn't exist, so it redirects you to index.php. Which creates a loop.

Remove the 3 lines, since you can't - from Nginx - deduce whether a given path exists or not. You don't know if a path exists until you hit the PHP container.